# i3wm: Duplicate workspace to new monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, configure, i3

I'm looking for a way to duplicate a workspace to another monitor (i3wm). I'm using arandr (screen layout manager), but workspaces are always split between screens. Let's say I'm making a presentation and workspace1 gets captured, then I can't see that workspace on my "laptop screen", because ONLY the "new view" would get this workspace. How can I duplicate a workspace (or maybe just re-display it - reading only)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution is to use "xrandr" and not the gui "arandr": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371793/how-to-duplicate-desktop-in-linux-with-xrandr

Comment: alternative partial arandr solution: layer both displays above each other (given the same resolution)

Answer (score 0):

i3 doesn't allow showing the same workspace on different monitors, but you could setup your displays as mirror instead of extend in xrandr or arandr (I think you need to set the same resolution on both displays and simply overlap them perfectly in arandr).

Comment: This approach for me doesn't work. I either set up projector (mirror of my second monitor) as secondary (variable used in my config - workspaces and i3blocks use it) and it works as long as projector is on. Or I set my secondary monitor directly and nothing works (workspaces are bound to it appear on primary, i3blocks doesn't show anything and thus windows supposed to go onto secondary [and mirrored projector] don't appear there).

Comment: @menfon I don't think you're describing the same issue as the question. I guess if someone asks people how to cook an egg and you try to cook a pie with those instructions and it doesn't work, it might not work.